# Is PDO_OCI classed as ODBC?

Tags: oracle, license

*I did post this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94087/is-pdo-oci-php-pdo-using-oracle-instant-client-classed-as-odbc anonymously, but then it wouldn't allow me to comment on it so I registered and am posting it again here. I'm not sure what else to do.*

I have a question that's been concerning me for some time.

We use Oracle at our company and we're about to upgrade to a newer release. I understand that Oracle have some additional licensing if you wish to connect to the database via ODBC.

My question is, we have a web application that connects to the Oracle database using PDO_OCI (PHP PDO using the Oracle Instant Client) - is this classed as accessing the Oracle database via ODBC?

In answer to this comment on the original question:

> "I understand that Oracle have some additional licensing if you wish
>   to connect to the database via ODBC" - where did you read that? The
>   connection method is mostly irrelevant for licensing AFAIK

I'm not sure. I asked our software vendor to upgrade our Oracle database version and they are doing this but have raised a question "Do you access our database directly via ODBC? As this affects our licensing costs.".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off-topic. Talk to your Oracle rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCI ([Oracle Call Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090945.html)) is not ODBC. ODBC drivers may use OCI, but not the other way round.

I've never heard of Oracle charging for ODBC drivers/access. In fact, there's no mention of an ODBC component in the global price list (link [here](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf)).

I would clarify with your vendor - maybe they're trying to extract some cash out of you by supplying/supporting some kind of additional product, or maybe it's just a miscommunication.